# GLMM with beta distribution and lots of zeros in y variable

Tags: r, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I am trying to run a glmm with a beta distribution using the glmmTMB function (package glmmTMB). My response variable has a lot of 0 observations so I get this error when running the model

Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 < y < 1

I have attached what my response variable looks like regular and also normalized (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zero values cannot occur in data that are truly Beta-distributed (the probability density of `y==0` is either zero or infinite unless the first shape parameter is *exactly* 1.0). You can fit a zero-inflated Beta response by specifying `ziformula`. For example:

### simulate data

```r
set.seed(101)
y <- rbeta(1000, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 5)
y[sample(1000, replace= FALSE, size = 100)] <- 0
dd <- data.frame(y)
```

### fit

```r
library(glmmTMB)
glmmTMB(y ~ 1, ziformula = ~1, data = dd, family = beta_family)
```

This example doesn't have a random-effects component, but that doesn't change anything important.